# SQL: select where either column is matched

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'll illustrate my problem:

Look at the table with two columns: Col1 and Col2.

```
-----------------   
| Col1  | Col2  |
-----------------
| 1a1   | 2b2   |
-----------------
| 11b   | 22a   |
-----------------
```

I am trying to select values that contain an **`a`** in either column.

The desired output would be:

```
------------
| MyNewCol |
------------
| 1a1      |
------------
| 22a      |
------------
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select col1 as newCol
from your_table
where charindex('a', col1) > 0
union all
select col2
from your_table
where charindex('a', col2) > 0
```

Comment: Wow... I bang my head against the wall for an hour and you come up with that in seconds! Works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT col1 AS output_col
FROM your_table
WHERE CHARINDEX('a', col1, 1) > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT col2
FROM your_table
WHERE CHARINDEX('a', col2, 1) > 0
```

It finds records where either value contains 'a' and performs a UNION ALL. If there are more than 2 columns, a different approach may be needed, as having a lot of UNIONs may cause performance issues.

Comment: Thanks bbrumm. I'll accept juergen's answer just because he beat you by a couple seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNION ALL statement

```
SELECT  [Col1] as MyNewCol FROM [Table] where Col1 like '%a%'
UNION ALL
SELECT  [Col2] as MyNewCol FROM [Table] WHERE Col2 like '%a%'
```

or UNION if you need distinct results

Comment: In the production table I actually use `LIKE '%a%`. `UNION ALL` is where I stumbled and you all got it right. Thanks Vasyl.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to do this using `CROSS APPLY` just requires single table scan

```
SELECT MyNewCol
FROM   Yourtable 
       CROSS apply(SELECT Col1
                   WHERE  [Col1] LIKE '%a%'
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT Col2
                   WHERE  [Col2] LIKE '%a%') cs (MyNewCol)
```

- [**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/RDB66919)